# Accessing LoginContext from an OSGi bundle in IBM Liberty

Tags: osgi, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to perform a user authentication from within an `OSGi bundle` deployed inside the `IBM WebSphere Liberty server`.

If I try

**ctx = new LoginContext("system.DEFAULT", handler);**

**ctx.login();**

I get the exception:
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.security.LoginModuleProxy cannot be found by ...

The same happens if I use

**ctx = new LoginContext("WSLogin", handler);**

**ctx.login();**

How can I properly use the LoginContext within an OSGi bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to achieve the result is quite similar:

```
final LoginContext ctx = new LoginContext("WSLogin",WSCallbackHandlerFactory.getInstance().getCallbackHandler(username, password));

ctx.login();
```

In the previous implementation the error was due to changing the calls loader before creating the login context.
The faulty code was:

```
    final LoginContext ctx;
    ClassLoader oldClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        ctx = new LoginContext("RealmUsersRoles", handler);
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(oldClassLoader);
    }
```